# In ArcMap, when I use PointsToLine in ArcToolbox, error appears

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, points-to-line, importerror, python-window

In ArcMap, I open the Python window and print some codes as followed:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data"
arcpy.PointsToLine_management("calibration_points.shp",
                              "C:/output/output.gdb/out_lines",
                              "ROUTE1", "MEASURE")
```

> Runtime error   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy__init__.py", line 21, in
>   
>       from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing__init__.py", line
>   14, in 
>       from _base import *
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   598, in 
>       env = GPEnvironments(gp)
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   595, in GPEnvironments
>       return GPEnvironment(geoprocessor)
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   548, in **init**
>       import weakref
>
> File "C:\Users\yanglan\Anaconda2\Lib\weakref.py", line 14, in
>   
>       from _weakref import ( ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

i want to know whether this error has a correlation with the anaconda2 installed in my computer, so curious about how to fix this problem

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Please always provide code and any error messages as text rather than pictures.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Wow, that is quite an error.. unfortunately it has to do with a module called weakref and not arcpy. You could edit c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\\_base.py and comment out line 548, be sure to remove the _base.pyc if it exists, as it sounds like weakref is no longer installed. If you're not comfortable with that then reinstall ArcGIS but there's no guarantee Anaconda will work afterwards.

Comment: i open c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py and line  548 shows "import weakref". there is a warn "'weakref' imported but unused" in this line. should i delete this line?

Comment: Why delete when you can comment out to test it.

Comment: i found the reason. the anaconda infects the run of arcgis. if upinstall the anaconda, the arcgis can show the correct result. so do you know how to run the arcgis insulating anaconda